# How to add a new Language(similar with javascript) in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to develop a vscode extension to support a new language(like script.code) in vscode. Actually this language is very similar with Javascript, I just add some new intellisence and snipets, also my own debugger.
My problem is for the intellisence how to show the ECMAScript intellisence in my language file. For example, if I input Object, the intellisence list did't show the es6's option. I want to this file behave like Javascript file, also with my own intellisence and snippet. Any suggestions and comments are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Developing extension or giving support to new language or creating new code snippets in visual code can be done in many ways.

**Best way and simple way is as below:**

**Prerequisite:**
**Node**
If not install node from *https://nodejs.org/en/download/*

Once this is done check for 
**node -v and npm -v**, You should get version of node and NPM

Then install yeoman and yeoman VS Code Generator from git bash
type in below command

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
yo code
```

**Select option** : New Language Support

Then edit the auto generator files and give the extension name in package.json

Debug the extension, once done publish it.